# Python NameError when var IS most definitely defined

Tags: python

```
def make_pdf(self):
        self.get_filez()
        self.get_client()
        file_name = self.client_id+"_"+self.client_name+"_"+self.batch_num
        style = libxslt.parseStylesheetDoc(self.xsl_file)   
        transformation = style.applyStylesheet(self.xml_file,None)
        style.saveResultToFilename("tmp/"+file_name+".fo",transformation,0)
        style.freeStylesheet()
        self.xml_file.freeDoc()
        transformation.freeDoc()
        fop_cmd = "/usr/bin/xmlgraphics-fop"
        #file_name = self.tpa+"_"+self.be+"_"+self.batch_num
        cmd = [fop_cmd,"-fo","tmp/"+file_name+".fo","-pdf","tmp/"+file_name+".pdf"]
        #fop_transform = subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        #fop_log = "-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-\n"
        #fop_log = fop_log + time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %R:%S')+"\n"
        #fop_log = fop_log + file_name+".fo" + "\n"
        #fop_log =  fop_transform.communicate()[0]+"\n"
        #f = open("/tmp/error_log","a")
        #f.write(fop_log)
        #f.close()
```

OK If I comment out the cmd variable declaration the code runs and makes an fo file correctly. With is uncommented like it is above, I get a NameError on file_name is not defined (which it is in the top). If I uncomment the second declaration of file_name right above the cmd declaratioin, it thows a NameError on self. '.' In the past when this sort of thing happens, it is a syntax error. I am missing it, please helpz!

When the second declaration of file_name is commented out:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "make_pdfs.py", line 11, in ?
    from MakePdfs import MakePdfs
  File "/home/khouser/removed/removed/MakePdfs.py", line 16, in ?
    class MakePdfs:
  File "/home/khouser/removed/removed/MakePdfs.py", line 39, in MakePdfs
    cmd = [fop_cmd,"-fo","tmp/"+file_name+".fo","-pdf","tmp/"+file_name+".pdf"]
NameError: name 'file_name' is not defined
```

When the second declaration of file_name is uncommented:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "make_pdfs.py", line 11, in ?
    from MakePdfs import MakePdfs
  File "/home/khouser/removed/removed/MakePdfs.py", line 16, in ?
    class MakePdfs:
  File "/home/khouser/removed/removed/MakePdfs.py", line 38, in MakePdfs
    file_name = self.tpa+"_"+self.be+"_"+self.batch_num
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Comment: have you printed file_name to see what are you actually sending to the cmd list?. can you give your actual traceback.

Comment: @joaquin yep, it is as expected

Comment: Full tracebacks matter, not vague verbal descriptions of errors.

Comment: Could you perhaps have an invisible control character bouncing around in there? If you are on a Unix machine, try looking at `cat -A filename`.

Comment: if you print file_name just before the cmd list creation and you get a correct string it is not possible that `"tmp/"+file_name+".fo"` or `"tmp/"+file_name+".pdf"` give you any error because you are only concatenating strings and there is no more code below. Are you sure you are describing accurately your situation?

Comment: @delnan, I have gone over my indents with a fine tooth comb, this was one of the first things I checked, @unutbu, trying this now..

Comment: @joaquin, yes, if everything else is uncommented I get the same error, I have just narrowed it down to this line.

Comment: @Kacie: I see that you're not having an indentation error, I'm just saying that unprintable characters would propably "only" cause an indentation error and that I consioder ubuntu's guess rather unlikely for that reason. Re the traceback: It points to `MakePdfs` rather than `make_pdf`, why? Please show all the code relevant to the problem (if it's too much, paste it e.g. on http://ww.pastebin.com)

Comment: @delnan, you were right, the indents looked correct in jedit, but alas the last three lines were not indeneted but spaced boo!

@unutbu thanks, that is the answer you should add it under the answers, I would have never caught it without that nifty command. Thank you.

Comment: @delnan, make_pdfs is the script and MakePdfs is the class it calls where the error is happening. The make_pdf function from the MakePdfs class is called from make_pdfs script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mysterious NameErrors may arise from your file containing invisible control characters. On unix machines, you can spot these errors by looking at the output of

```
cat -A filename.py
```

Comment: It's a lot mysterious than it sounds. Mixed tabs/spaces can ruin indentation, specifically cause the latter part of a method to be interpreted as class-level statements. And of course you don't have `self` or a method's locals at class level.

Answer (score 1):

Try to print file_name after each line, to see if somebody is removing the "file_name" variable from your namespace.

In addition, to be more pythonic (and efficient), use

```
file_name = "_".join((self.client_id, self.client_name, self.batch_num))
```

to concatenate strings.

Comment: thanks for the pretty syntax, if you look at the comments above the problem was indentions

Answer (score 0):

If you're assigning `file_name` here:

```
file_name = self.client_id+"_"+self.client_name+"_"+self.batch_num
```

And you're getting a `NameError` reporting, that file_name is not defined, then try wrapping the operation in a `try..except`, to see what is going wrong:

```
try:
    file_name = self.client_id+"_"+self.client_name+"_"+self.batch_num
except NameError as err:
    print err, 'failed, here is some debug stuff:'
    print "CLIENT ID   =", self.client_id
    print "CLIENT NAME =", self.client_name
    print "BATCH NUM   =", self.batch_num
```

If any of this is failing, this will set you on the course to finding out why and narrowing down the cause of it.

Comment: Thank you, but I thought about that, I been wracking my brain for 2 hours now, turns out it was spaces instead of tabs :/