# Python: Indentation Error

Tags: python, indentation, python-idle

My younger cousin somehow got hold of a python book and has been trying to learn Python. He's asked me for help. But I'm having trouble doing that.

He is using IDLE and he reports that he gets this error:

```
               Error: Inconsistent indentation detected!

    1)      Your indentation is outright incorrect (easy to fix), OR
    2)      Your indentation mixes tabs and spaces.

                   To fix case 2, change all tabs to spaces by using Edit->Select All
                   Followed by Format->Untabify Region and specify the number of
                   Columns used by each tab.
```

He sent me a copy of his code, and the indentation is correct in it. It fails to run because of a number of syntax errors, but that's not important. He reports that he used the Format->Untabify Region but the problem was not fixed.

I can't for the life of me figure out why I can run his python file, but he can't. Does anybody have any idea what is going on with that? I'm sadly currently located a five hour plane flight away else I'd physically see what was going on.

His code is here, it doesn't have any indentation errors when I try to run it, so I doubt it tell you anything helpful. If there is a problem its been somehow removed by the time I got it.

```
import pygame, sys, random

skier_images = ["skier_down.png", "skier_right1.png",
                "skier_right2.png", "skier_left2.png",
                "skier_left1.png"]

class SkierClass(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self)
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("skier_down.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = [320, 100]
        self.angle = 0
    def turn(self, direction):
        self.angle = self.angle + direction
        if self.angle < -2: self.angle = -2
        if self.angle >  2: self.angle =  2
        center = self.rect.center
        self.image = pygame.image.load(skier_images[self.angle])
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = center
        speed = [self.angle, 6 - abs(self.angle) * 2]
        return speed
    def move(self, speed):
        self.rect.centerx = self.rect.centerx + speed [0]
        if self.rect.centerx < 20: self.rect.centerx =20
        if self.rect.centerx > 620: self.rect.centerx = 620

class ObstacleClass(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image_file, location, type):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image_file = image_file
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image_file)
        self.location = location
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = location
        self.type = type
        self.passed = False

    def scroll(self, t_ptr):
        self.rect.centery = self.location[1] - t_ptr

def create_map(start, end):
    obstacles = pygame.sprite.Group()
    gates = pygame.sprite.Group()
    locations = []
    for i in range(10):
        row = random.randint(start, end)
        col = random.randint(0, 9)
        location = [col * 64 + 20, row * 64 + 20]
        if not (location in locations):
            locations.append(location)
            type = random.choice(["tree", "flag"])
            if type == "tree": img = "skier_flag.png"
            obstacle = ObstacleClass(img, location, type)
            obstacles.add(obstacle)
    return obstacles
def animate():
    screen.fill(255, 255, 255])
    pygame.display.update(obstacles.draw(screen))
    screen.blit(skier.image, skier.rect)
    screen.blit(score_text, [10, 10])
    pygame.display.flip()
def updateObstaclegroup(map0, map1):
    obstacles = pygame.sprite.Group()
    for ob in map0:  obstacles.add(ob)
    for ob in map1:  obstacles.add(ob)
    return obstacles

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([640,640])
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
skier =SkierClass()
speed = [0, 6]
map_position = 0
points = 0
map0 = create_map(20, 29)
map1 = create_map(10, 19)
activeMap = 0
obstacles = updateObstacleGroup(map0, map1)
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 50)


while True:
    clock.tick(30)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                speed = skier.turn(-1)
            elif efvent.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                speed = skier.turn(1)
    skier.move(speed)
    map_position += speed[1]

    if map_position >=640 and activeMap == 0:
        activeMap = 1
        map0 = create)map(20, 29)
        obstacles = updateObstacleGroup (map0, map1)
    if map_position >=1280 and activeMap ==1:
        activeMap = 0
        for ob in map0:
                ob.location[1] = ob.location[1] - 1280
        map_position = map_position - 1280
        map1 = create_map(10, 19)
        obstacles = updateObstacleGroup (map0, map1)

    for obstacle in obstacles:
                obstacle.scroll(map_position)
    hit = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(skier, obstacles, False)
    if hit:
        if hit[0].type == "tree" and not hit[0].passed:
            points = points - 100
            skier.image = pygame.image.load("skier_crash.png")
            animate()
            pygame.time.delay(1000)
            skier.image = pygame.image.load("skier_down.png")
            speed = [0, 6]
            hit[0].passed = True
        elif hit[0].type == "flag" and not hit[0].passed:
            points += 10
            obstacles.remove (hit[0])


    score_text = font.render("Score: " +str(points), 1, (0, 0, 0))
    animate()
```

Comment: You vcan use [Teamviewer](http://teamviewer.com) to remotely watch his desktop.

Comment: Are you saying that if you fix the syntax errors then it runs fine on your computer, but that same file won't run on his? Maybe you should post the code.

Comment: @Gabe, I don't have any indentation errors in the copy I've gotten. I haven't tried sending him back the fixed version, maybe I'll try that. But it doesn't seem to solve the underlying problem of the myserious indentation error.

Comment: @cularis, now I feel stupid for not thinking about that.

Comment: @David, as I explained the code was useless, but its posted know if you want to see it.

Comment: and where is the error in this code?

Comment: @David, I have no idea. IDLE gives him a popup error and I think it escaped his notice if it indicated where the problem was. I've tried to explain in an e-mail what's up with that but I haven't gotten a response. I'm more wondering if anybody knows what could cause the problem such that the code is indented correctly when I get it.

Comment: this is not a question, I register my close vote

Comment: This question can't really be answered without having the actual file which fails to run (not the one which actually works). Ask him to upload the actual file somewhere without modifying anything. Are you sure you are running the same Python version?

Comment: @leoluk, he already sent me the file as an attachment. I don't really see what else I can ask him to do with the file.

Comment: I know the question can't really be answered, otherwise I would have answered it for him. I was hoping for somebody to point out a cause I hadn't considered.

Comment: It is actually possible to trigger an indentation error without indenting wrongly by, for example, writing `if Foo:` without an indented block. I suspect this to be the case here. By fixing the syntax errors, you fixed the indentation errors too.

Comment: @leoluk, I hadn't realized that. But still, that shouldn't show up as a syntax error on mine and an indentation error on his. Should it?

Comment: Maybe different Python version -> different error interpretation?

Answer (score 5):

```
with open('problem_script.py','r') as f:
    content = f.read()
    print(repr(content))
```

Chances are good there are hidden invisible characters in his file. Using the program above will help him find them.

Comment: hmm... maybe. But how would he have managed to put those in?

Comment: I don't know, but somehow [it happens](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5756777/python-nameerror-when-var-is-most-definitely-defined). Maybe the code was typed in using a word processor instead of a programming editor?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is a Windows/Unix line ending issue. Are you exchanging the python code between two different operating systems? If so try running dos2unix or unix2dos to set the line endings to the proper format on the system IDLE is running.

Comment: Good thought. He runs windows, I run linux. But I tried doing it on a windows machine and it gives the same results.