# Irregular Error - python cv2.imshow NameError: name "definition" is not defined

Tags: python, opencv, nameerror, imshow

I am running a video feed through a `cv2.imshow` operator. Most of the time, the code runs when I call it in command line, but occasionally I get the following NameError:

```
NameError: name 'masked' is not defined
```

However, 'masked' is absolutely defined before it is called in cv2.imshow:

```
image = frame.array

miniframe = image

masked = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=circle_img)

cv2.imshow("frame", masked)
```

same thing happens when 'masked' is defined this way:

```
image = frame.array

miniframe = image

M = np.float32([[1,0,x+w/2],[0,1,y+h/2]])
masked  = cv2.warpAffine(image, M, (x+w, y+h))

cv2.imshow("frame", masked)
```

When `print masked` is inserted above the `cv2.imshow` line, it results in the array printed as numbers - when the code is working. When it is not working, it results in the NameError traceback pointing to `print masked`.

And to be clear, in either scenario the NameError happens seemingly randomly, without modification to the code. So, I can run it once or 20 times just fine, but then it will suddenly not work in command line, with a traceback to the `cv2.imshow` line. Sometimes, copy-pasting identical blocks of code from previous versions will get it to work again, but after a few unmodified tries, back to `NameError`.

I have read over [Python NameError when var IS most definitely defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5756777/python-nameerror-when-var-is-most-definitely-defined), and used `cat -A filename.py` to check the invisible control characters. After de- and re-indenting, it worked 2 more times, and then right back to the NameError.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You're missing a fairly substantial amount of your traceback - *especially* the line on which it happens.

Comment: Also, do you have your files [under version control](http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/)? That will tell you if any changes were made to your file.

Comment: Great git link! Thank you. I resolved my problem, will post the solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a resolution. My problem was related to a condition in 'masked' that was not fulfilled. This is a program that relies on face detection, but my problem would be the same for any random, ongoing condition that must be fulfilled.

Troubleshooting steps included:
- reviewing my tracebacks
- testing IRL by having a face in front of the camera on start, and then a hand over the camera on start. This confirmed that the program would run if a face was detected on start, but not if there was no face.

To resolve the issue, I used a try/except condition for `cv2.imshow("frame", masked)`, resulting in code that looked like:

```
image = frame.array

miniframe = image

M = np.float32([[1,0,x+w/2],[0,1,y+h/2]])
masked  = cv2.warpAffine(image, M, (x+w, y+h))

try:
    cv2.imshow("frame", masked)
except NameError:
    cv2.imshow("frame", image)
```

I am a rank beginner, this really taught me the value of testing and reviewing tracebacks!

Answer (score 0):

please import google patches, the code for that is-

```
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
```

And the full import lines should be

import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34408239)